# How to solve these trignometric limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

1. $$\lim_{θ \to \pi/12}\frac{12\cos\theta \sin\theta-3}{12\theta-\pi}$$
2. $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\cos(e^x)}{\sqrt x} $$

Answers: 1) $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ 2)0

Edit: my teacher just corrected the problem. the numerator was supposed to be $12cos\theta sin\theta-3$

Comment: not sure about the square root as an answer, to be honest. I got zero in both. For the first one you just plug in and for the second one use the fact, that cos is bounded from both sides and then use the squeeze theorem I think it is called.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The first problem is supposed to be the limit as x approaches pi/12. I edited it just now

Comment: kindly include your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For 1, divide both top and bottom by 12 and recall the definition of a derivative.

For 2, $-1\leq\cos(f(x))\leq1$ for any $x$ in the domain of $f$ where $f$ is a real valued function.

Answer (score 0):

> The first limit is NOT defined.

It is due to the fact that it is NOT any of the indeterminate forms we have, in fact it is $\frac 3 \infty$. That I'd argue as zero and not as a standard limit.

To know this, just use $2\sin\theta\cos\theta = \sin2\theta$, thus we get:

$$lim_{\theta \to \frac \pi {12}} \frac {6\sin2\theta} {12\theta-\pi}$$

For the second limit, Apply the squeeze theorem, like this:

$$-1\le \cos(e^x) \le 1$$

$$lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {-1} {\sqrt{x}} \le lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {\cos(e^x)} {\sqrt{x}} \le lim_{x \to \infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt{x}}$$

Also, $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {-1} {\sqrt{x}} = lim_{x \to \infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt{x}} = 0$$

So second limit evaluates to a $0$.

Answer (score 0):

1. The denominator tends to zero, but the numerator doesn't (it tends to $6\sin\dfrac\pi6$), hence no limit.
2. $\left|\dfrac{\cos e^x}{\sqrt x}\right|\le\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\to0.$